# Using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to find derivative of $\int_k^\infty (s-k)\pi(s)ds$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, chain-rule

I am trying to run through this example as a learning exercise, but I am not getting the result.
Define 
$$
C_t = \int_k^\infty (s-k)\pi(s)ds
$$
Where $\pi$ is some function (that satisfies whatever basic assumptions are necessary) $\pi$ is not actually known, though, so we cannot explicitly integrate this.

The goal (and my question) is to find 
$$
\frac{dC}{dk}
$$

So first I notice that this has $\infty$ as an upper limit, so I rewrite it as 
$$
C_t = \int_k^b (s-k)\pi(s)ds
$$
and, once this is evaluated, I will take the limit of the result as $b\to \infty$.

My attempt is to say that
$$
C_t = \int_k^b s\pi(s)ds - \int_k^b k\pi(s)ds
$$
Next, letting
$$
F(k) = \int_k^b s\pi(s)ds,\; G(k) = \int_k^b k\pi(s)ds\\
f(s) = s\pi(s);\; g(s) = k\pi(s)
$$
I thought that the fundamental theorem of calculus (+ chain rule) tells us that
$$
\frac{dC}{dk} = [F'(b)\frac{db}{dk} - F'(k)] +[G'(b)\frac{db}{dk} - G'(k)]
$$
where $F'(b) = b\pi(b)$, and $G'(b) = k\pi(b)$, $G'(k) = F'(k) = k \pi(k)$.

But then $G'(k)$ cancels with $F'k$ and we get 
$$(b\pi(b) - k\pi(b))\frac{db}{dk}$$
I have two problems with this: The first is that I have no clue what $\frac{db}{dk}$ is. I feel like it should be $0$ since $b$ is just some upper bound, a constant...

and two: **The answer is that**
$$\frac{dC}{dk} = -\int_k^\infty \pi(s)\cdot ds$$
I never took the limit at the end, so perhaps I would get the infinity upper bound if I did so, but I don't understand how the integral sign remains, now how this result is obtained?

Comment: Since $b$ is a constant and $k$ is your variable, you should switch the order of integration.  Note that $F(k)=-\int_{b}^{k}s\pi(s)ds$, so that $F'(k)=-k\pi(k)$, for example.  For $G(k)$, since $k$ is independent of the integration variable $s$, you may write $G(k)=-k\int_{b}^{k}\pi(s)ds$ and then use the product rule to obtain $G'(k)$.  Precisely, $G'(k)=-\int_{b}^{k}\pi(s)ds-k\pi(k)$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Comment: @SinisterCutlass I did not think of changing $b$ and $k$, and that makes a big difference. I did think of pulling out the $k$ but did not think of the product rule. Thank you, that solve my question.

If you post it as an answer I will accept it.